# Sticker not match the model after rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image: Sticker not match the model after rendering. How can I fix this.]

Sticker not match the model after rendering. How can I fix this.

Comment: Apart from the visual problem: Is it really a good idea to (graphically) suggest pouring hot coffee into a thin-walled glass without handle? Just a thought. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying the right screen is correct ... So that is just because of viewport limitation.

The left image (render) is actually a result of your shader setup ... Sticker appears on outter side and is doubled by appearing also on inner side of glass wall.

We don't know nothing about your material setup or model, but if you are using solidify modifier you should apply it and use UV texture coordinates to specify where sticker should appear.

Or more flexible way ... use a sticker as separate plane object Shrinkwrapped onto glass model (or deformed by another way around glass surface).